# Is it mandatory to name methods in a controller starting with HTTP verbs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem understanding Routing in ASP.NET MVC, the version is 5 to be specific.

Is it mandatory to have methods return an ActionResult?
Is it mandatory to have method names start with any one of the HTTP verbs.

Can someone, please give me an example of how the route would look for a method like so:

```
[Queryable]
public IQueryable<Student> GetStudentCategories(string StudentId)
{

 // some code that returns an IQueryable 
}
```

This works:

```
http://localhost:32944/odata/StudentSet?StudentId=40
```

What to do if it has to work like this:

```
http://localhost:32944/odata/StudentSet/GetStudentCategories?StudentId=40
```

What to do if I want to call the methods which are in StudentSet ODataController with this pattern:

```
http://localhost:32944/odata/StudentSet/
```

The reason I am asking this is because I am having a very tough time trying to get a route work for ODataController and I have asked a lot of question in the last two days without any success.
So now I want to understand how OData routing is different from the default routing.

Please help, this is driving me crazy.

Regards.

Comment: what is StudentSet means?  class or controller name ?

Comment: StudentSet is an ODataController